# Convex hull routines in scipy.spatial gives me back my original set of points

Tags: python, scipy, spatial, convex-hull, delaunay

I have a set of points and want to find the convex hull. When I give them to scipy.spatial (either ConvexHull or Delaunay), I just get the original set of points back. By construction, this should not be the case.

Here are [the points](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21734889/points.p) as a pickled numpy array. My code is given below:

```
import pickle
from scipy import spatial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = pickle.load( open( "points.p", "rb" ) )

hullpoints = spatial.ConvexHull(points).points


# plot points
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
# ax.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], points[:, 2], 'r.') # original points
ax.plot(hullpoints[:, 0], hullpoints[:, 1], hullpoints[:, 2], 'r.') # convex hull of points


# set labels and show()
ax.set_xlabel('Player 1')
ax.set_ylabel('Player 2')
ax.set_zlabel('Player 3')
plt.show()
```

Obviously some of these points are interior to the convex hull and should be removed via spatial.ConvexHull(points) or spatial.Delaunay(points), as done in the 2d examples given [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html#scipy.spatial.ConvexHull).

Does anyone know why I'm getting the original set of points back? I could brute-force find the exterior points and plot only those (ultimate goal is a surface plot for exterior shape approximated by the points), but it seems that scipy.spatial should be able to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your are using the `.points` attribute which gives you back the input points. Try to use the `.simplices` attribute instead, which gives you the "points forming the simplical facets of the convex hull".

[See the documentation for more info.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html#scipy.spatial.ConvexHull)

Comment: It's probably `hull.points[np.unique(hull.simplices)]` that he wants to call to get the actual list of unique points in the convex hull.

Comment: That does it! Thanks so much.

Comment: If you are looking for points to create a polygon geometry then `hull.points[hull.vertices]` will give you the points in the desired sequence.